# Use current branch as filename

Tags: bash, git

Most of the times I generate a diff file for my branches, like so: `git diff trunk.. > .git/diffs/branch_name.diff`

What I would like to do is change `branch_name` to the output of `git branch --show-current`.
I've tried doin something like `git diff trunk.. > '.git/diffs/+$(git branch --show-current)+.diff'` but that stores it with the filename literary as `+$(git branch --show-current)+.diff`

Is there a way for me to do this as a one liner?

Comment: Replace single quotes `'` with double quotes `"` so that process substitution takes place.

Comment: Unless you're developing new Git commands to contribute back to the Git project, it's probably wisest to avoid creating files and directories inside the `.git` directory itself. Git currently makes no use of `.git/diffs/` (so it's safe-ish to create and use this yourself) but you are setting yourself up for possible surprises this way.

Comment: @torek good point, thanks for bringing that up!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unix shells ignore metacharacters inside single quotes (apostrophes). Use double quotes or no quotes:

```
git diff trunk.. > ".git/diffs/+$(git branch --show-current)+.diff"
```

or

```
git diff trunk.. > .git/diffs/+$(git branch --show-current)+.diff
```

PS. Some metacharacters are ignored in double quotes too. Most notable is `*`. Compare `echo *` and `echo "*"`

Comment: You should never advocate for removing double quotes around parameter expansions, command substitutions etc, without talking about word splitting and pathname expansion. Consider this example: `a="*"; echo $a;` vs `a="*"; echo "$a";`

Comment: Not working... `bash: .git/diffs/+$(git branch --show-current)+.diff: No such file or directory`...

Comment: @MattiasThalén The directory `.git/diffs` must be created first. You cannot redirect to a file in a non-existing directory.

Comment: @phd it does exists. when I put it in single quotes I get a file called `+$(git branch --show-current)+.diff` inside the folder `.git/diff`

Comment: `git diff trunk.. > ".git/diffs/+$(git branch --show-current)+.diff"`was working... the issue was that I had `/` in my branch name, and bash wanted to treat that as a folder structure.

Comment: I solved it by doing some string replacements: `".diffs/$(git branch --show-current | sed 's/\//_-_/g').diff"`